# how to render SimpleBannerComponent in spartacus

Tags: javascript, angular, spartacus-storefront

I have two components, a CmsFlexComponent

```
INSERT_UPDATE CMSFlexComponent;$contentCV[unique=true];uid[unique=true];name;flexType;&componentRef
;;VideoListingComponent;VideoListingComponent;VideoListingComponent;VideoListingComponent
```

and a SimpleBannerComponent

```
;;VideoListingComponent;VideoListingComponent;VideoListingComponent;VideoListingComponent 
 INSERT_UPDATE Media; $contentCV[unique = true]; code[unique = true]; mime     ; realfilename; @media[translator = de.hybris.platform.impex.jalo.media.MediaDataTranslator][forceWrite = true]; folder(qualifier)[default = 'images']
               ;                          ; banner1            ; text/jpg ; banner1.jpg ; $jarResourceCms/banner1.jpg

INSERT_UPDATE SimpleBannerComponent; $contentCV[unique = true]; uid[unique = true]    ; name                   ; &componentRef       ; $picture[lang = $lang]
                               ;                          ; VideoListPageBanner   ; Video List Page Banner ; VideoListPageBanner ; banner1
```

In Spartacus, I have defined a mapping as follow:
    export const videoListingConfig = {
  cmsComponents: {

```
VideoListingComponent: {
      component: VideoListingComponent
    },
    VideoListPageBanner:{
      component: VideoListPageBannerComponent
    }    
}

  }
```

I want access to the second banner component:
So in that component ts file, I have injected

```
private component: CmsComponentData<CmsBannerComponent>
```

When I try to print

```
    this.component.data$.subscribe(comp => this.cmsComp = comp);
console.log(this.component);
```

I always get the first components data back.  What am I doing wrong.  I think this works out-of-the-box.

Comment: If I do something like this, it works:
this.cmsService.getComponentData(
      'VideoListPageBanner'
    ).subscribe(res => {
            this.data = res;
          });

Answer (score 0):

You cannot map component IDs of individual instances to components in Spartacus, you can only map Commerce component types to Spartacus components.  The exception is CMSFlexComponents where the flexType value is mapped.  See: https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/customizing-cms-components/ and https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/banner-component/

For reference, the standard Spartacus code that sets up SimpleBannerComponent mapping in in *banner.module.ts*:

```
ConfigModule.withConfig(<CmsConfig>{
  cmsComponents: {
    SimpleResponsiveBannerComponent: {
      component: BannerComponent,
    },
    BannerComponent: {
      component: BannerComponent,
    },
    SimpleBannerComponent: {
      component: BannerComponent,
    },
  },
}),
```

With your second component you are trying to map a UID (VideoListPageBanner) and that will not work.

Comment: the UID component I am trying to match is a SimpleBannerComponent.  Will it work if I do the mapping => ConfigMaodule.withConfig(CmsConfig>{cmsComponents: {SimpleBannerComponent:VideoListPageBannerComponent}}

Comment: no actually, that replaced even the logo with the spartacus component, which is not what I want.

Comment: The mapping is at a component type level, not individual components.  What you would do with that is map ALL SimpleBannerComponents in SAP Commerce to a VidoeListPageBannerComponent in Spartacus

Comment: I am not entirely sure what you are trying to achieve here.  If you just need a banner for your video list page ... why not just use SimpleBannerComponent & include it in the correct ContentSlot for your video list page?  If you want to then change the layout, perhaps CSS would be sufficient?

Comment: I already have the SimpleBannerComponent and added it to the content slot:
     INSERT_UPDATE SimpleBannerComponent; $contentCV[unique = true]; uid[unique = true]    ; name                   ; &componentRef       ; $picture[lang = $lang]
                                   ;                          ; VideoListPageBanner   ; Video List Page Banner ; VideoListPageBanner ; banner1

Comment: INSERT_UPDATE ContentSlot ; $contentCV[unique = true] ; uid[unique = true]             ; name                                       ; active ; cmsComponents(&componentRef) ;   ;   ;
                          ;                           ; BannerContentSlot              ; banner Content Slot                        ; true   ; VideoListPageBanner          ;   ;   ;